# 404 not found image using Alias in apache2

Tags: apache2

I have set up a really basic site using the default apache2 config settings, and I can't get an alias directory set up properly.

I've tried following a number of guides and stackexchange posts on setting this up, but there must be something I'm still missing. I've gone through a number of versions of this and tried to simplify as much as possible.

Here's my apache2 default site config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        Alias /js/ "/usr/share/apache2/js/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/apache2/js/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The alias from the default configuration in mods-available/alias.conf, `Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/apache2/icons"` works fine. I can access `siteurl.com/icons/a.gif`, but `siteurl.com/js/a.gif` is giving me a 404 error, despite there being a copy of `a.gif` in that folder.

I've done `service apache2 restart`. I've tried a2enmod/a2ensite to re-add the config files, but it says they are already loaded. This seems really simple, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the server and clearing the browser cache it is working properly.